# How to uninstall ClickOnce application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, installation, clickonce

I was looking everywhere for this answer, but all related questions on SO are very old. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266858/uninstall-clickonce-clients) question is from 2009 and the best (and only answer) has 3 steps. Really? I mean.. isn't Uninstaller a basic feature of every Installer?

Why Microsoft would create a feature that basically installs your app without an option of uninstalling it? That doesn't make sense at all.. so I really hope I just couldn't find it and there is an easy way to uninstall "ClickOnce" application.

EDIT:
I'm using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: which version of visual studio do you have?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw 2015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this answer on msdn forums. Hope it would be helpful.

[MSDN Forum Question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f494f222-25d0-4805-a60b-38ae42692082/programmatically-uninstall-clickonce-application?forum=winformssetup)

> Hi,
>
> You can create a cmd file and type the uninstall string. Then add a
>   shortcut to this cmd file and put it to user’s program folder.
>
> Check this thread:
>   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/4b681725-faaa-48c3-bbb0-02ebf3926e25
>
> To find the “uninstall string”, you could search it in the registry:
>
> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/9a60c9ab-5d75-4d11-98e2-fd3b83f800ed/
>
> You could also create a console application for this. And put the
>   execute file with the deploy project then create a shortcut or copy
>   this file to the user’s program folder.
>
> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/717cfce0-3061-400f-9ea3-069f73f3a473
>   (The first FAQ)
>
> By the way, there is an article tells create uninstall shortcut for
>   clickonce:
>
> http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/38ac5c61-4e9d-49eb-90d3-7911815e2244/create-uninstall-option-f.aspx
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Ling Wang

Comment: Does that mean, that I need to create totally new project? A console project? Or this `protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)` is inside Windows Service?

Comment: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/38ac5c61-4e9d-49eb-90d3-7911815e2244/create-uninstall-option-f.aspx seems cool.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but Louisa Bickley asked for a simple solution. On Windows you go to `Add/Remove programs`, search for your application and remove it.

Note: This will only remove your installed application, not the entire project files. After uninstalling you can install your one-click application again in another folder.